# always @* block in sequential circuit

Tags: fpga, verilog

as far as I know, always @* block is used in combinational circuit, and

the logic inside the always @* are sequentially executed regardless of the clock (asynchronous).

However, it seems that the logic inside always @* block in the below code

works synchronously according to the rising edge of the clock.

```
module univ_bin_counter
#(
  parameter N = 8
)
(
  input wire clk, reset,
  input wire syn_clr, load, en, up,
  input wire [N-1:0] d,
  output wire max_tick, min_tick,
  output wire [N-1:0] q
);

  //signal declaration
  reg [N-1:0] r_reg, r_next;

  //body
  always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
    if (reset)
      r_reg <= 0;
    else
      r_reg <= r_next;
  //next statement

  always @*
    if (syn_clr)
      r_next = 0;
    else if (load)
      r_next = d;
    else if (en && up)
      r_next = r_reg + 1;
    else if (en && ~up)
      r_next = r_reg - 1;
    else
      r_next = r_reg;
  //output statement
  assign q = r_reg;
  assign max_tick = (r_reg == {N{1'b1}});
  assign min_tick = (r_reg == 0);
endmodule
```

Before I run the simulation, I expected that the syn_clr works asynchronously but it works synchronously.

[image: Although the syn_clr is set at 90ns, the data q[2:0] becomes zero at the next rising edge of the clk.]
Although the syn_clr is set at 90ns, the data q[2:0] becomes zero at the next rising edge of the clk.

If my understanding is right, it should be located in the above

```
always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
```

block instaed of **always @*** block.

Could you explain what makes the always@* block executed synchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `always @*` statement executes asynchrounously. It is equivalent to writing the code below:

```
always begin
     // wait for one of these signals to change
     @(syn_clr or load or up or en or r_reg)
     if (syn_clr)
      r_next = 0;
    else if (load)
      r_next = d;
    else if (en && up)
      r_next = r_reg + 1;
    else if (en && ~up)
      r_next = r_reg - 1;
    else
      r_next = r_reg;
end
```

If you look at the value of `r_next`, you will see that it gets evaluated after any change in the listed signals. It may be that all those signals are changing on a clock edge as well, so you don't see the difference.